# Adding sub-subcommands to a command

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script that takes input from CLI, parses it and runs the appropriate function:

`command subcommand subsubcommand1 --arg1 <value1>`

When user doesn't provide subsubcommand I want the script to return an error, saying that at least one of the supported subcommand must be provided, instead it returns:

`Namespace object has no attribute func`

This is the code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='The highlevel command')
parser.add_argument("-v", help="some help text", action='store_true', default=False)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
subparsers.required = True

subcommand_parser = subparsers.add_parser('subcommand', help='some help text for the subcommand')
subsub_subparser = subcommand_parser.add_subparsers()
subsubparser1 = subsub_subparser.add_parser('subsubcommand1', help='some help text for the subsubcommand1')
subsubparser1.set_defaults(action='subsubcommand_action', func=mylib.subsub1)
subsubparser1.add_argument('--arg1', required=True, help='arg1')
subsubparser1.add_argument('--arg2', required=False, default='hello', help='arg2')
```

How can I fix the current error and make the new error show up?

Comment: Can you give an example of the CLI call you want to return the error?

Comment: Consider `click` http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/commands/

Comment: You set `dest` and `required` for `subparsers`.  Why not for `subsub_subparser`?

Comment: Where's the code that looks for `args.func`, the line that raises the error?  `args.func` will only be set if the `subsubparser1` is used.  If it's possible that it isn't set, your use has to take that into account, either with a `try/except` wrapper, or with a `hasattr` test.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the omissions mentioned in my comments:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='The highlevel command')
parser.add_argument("-v", help="some help text", action='store_true', default=False)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
subparsers.required = True

subcommand_parser = subparsers.add_parser('subcommand', help='some help text for the subcommand')
subsub_subparser = subcommand_parser.add_subparsers(dest='subaction')   # EDIT
subsub_subparser.required = True             # EDIT
subsubparser1 = subsub_subparser.add_parser('subsubcommand1', help='some help text for the subsubcommand1')
subsubparser1.set_defaults(func="mylib.subsub1")          # EDIT
subsubparser1.add_argument('--arg1', required=True, help='arg1')
subsubparser1.add_argument('--arg2', required=False, default='hello', help='arg2')

subsubparser2 = subsub_subparser.add_parser('subsubcommand2')  # EDIT

args = parser.parse_args()     
print(args)               # EDIT
if hasattr(args, 'func'):
    print('func: ',args.func)
else:
    print('func not defined')
```

sample runs:

```
2020:~/mypy$ python3 stack56435945.py 
usage: stack56435945.py [-h] [-v] {subcommand} ...
stack56435945.py: error: the following arguments are required: action

2021:~/mypy$ python3 stack56435945.py subcommand
usage: stack56435945.py subcommand [-h] {subsubcommand1,subsubcommand2} ...
stack56435945.py subcommand: error: the following arguments are required: subaction

2021:~/mypy$ python3 stack56435945.py subcommand subsubcommand1 --arg1 foobar
Namespace(action='subcommand', arg1='foobar', arg2='hello', func='mylib.subsub1', subaction='subsubcommand1', v=False)
func:  mylib.subsub1

2022:~/mypy$ python3 stack56435945.py subcommand subsubcommand2
Namespace(action='subcommand', subaction='subsubcommand2', v=False)
func not defined
```

Comment: When I type `command subcommand` I get this error: 
```usage: command subcommand {subsubcommand1} ...
command subcommand: error: the following arguments are required: subaction```
While `subsction` shouldn't be required or displayed to the user

Comment: 'subaction' is the `dest` I gave `subsub_subparser`.  It has to have a `dest` in order to issue an `required` error (which is what you want, right?).  Choose the names that work for you.  My main point is that nested subcommands work just like the first level.

Comment: Ah, I see I got it. That `subaction` is just a name to help user understand what they should provide, right?